# Как в Django template задать значение title?

Tags: python, django, django-view, django-template

Как в `Django template` задать название для `title`?

**Template**

```
{% block title %}{{latest_Panel_list.article_title}}{% endblock %}
```

**View**

```
def navigation_bar(request):
    latest_Panel_list = Panel.objects.order_by('id')[:1]
    latest_information_list = information.objects.order_by('id')[:1]
    return render(request, 'Hom/hom.html', {'latest_Panel_list': latest_Panel_list, 'latest_information_list':latest_information_list})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- В чём смысл этого среза?

  `latest_Panel_list = Panel.objects.order_by('id')[:1]`

  Это будет возвращать список из одного элемента. Так и должно быть?

  Предлагаю переделать на

  `latest_Panel_list = Panel.objects.order_by('id')[0]`

  Это просто будет возвращать этот элемент. Тогда в шаблоне можно будет вывести его так:

  `<title>{% block title %}{{latest_Panel_list.article_title}}{% endblock %}</title>`
- Ну а если всё-таки вам нужен этот *список с одним элементом*, тогда в шаблоне го можно вывести так

  `<title>{% block title %}{{latest_Panel_list.0.article_title}}{% endblock %}</title>`

**P.S.** Это при условии, что у объекта `latest_Panel_list` есть атрибут `article_title`